# document.location.href is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I need to reload the current page with the selected value on the form, below is the code but it is not working on IE.

Can any one please help me on this??

```
  <script> 
  function refreshPage(org_cfu) 
  {  
      window.event.returnValue = false;
      url = '<@VAR request$baseref
     encoding='none'>&_module=shell_user_mgr&_function=nrform&org_cfu='+org_cfu
     alert(url); document.location.href=url 
  } 
  </script>

 <SELECT NAME="org_cfu" SIZE=1 onChange="refreshPage(this.value);" class="single-multiselect-simple"> 
 <OPTION VALUE="">Please Select</OPTION> 
 <OPTION VALUE="Admin">Admin</option>                    
 <OPTION VALUE="WHS">WHS</option> 
 <OPTION VALUE="SMB">SMB</option> 
 </Select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Would be the preferred way of doing this.

Comment: I would think this is the best way, considering it is assigning a string literal, as opposed to `window.location = url` which invokes the setter method to assign a value to `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
```

or:

```
window.navigate("http://www.yoururl.com");
```

Comment: Could you provide some documentation on why `window.navigate` is even a good idea?

Comment: You just posted a link to a Google search page?

Comment: I know it. What do you want more?

Comment: both Window.location and window.navigate are not working.. note: above code is working on chrome and firefox, i m facing problem only in IE

Answer (score 0):

*location* is a property of **window**.
Try: **window**.location.href